# Calculating difference when N/A's are present

Tags: r, na, calculated-columns

I have a table (listed below) in which we measured Temperature from a well. Unfortunately (mainly due to weather) there wasn't always water in the wells that could be measured so we have NA's persistent.

```
   Date   Temp(C)
   09-22    14
   09-29    19.6
   10-15    NA
   10-28    11
   11-06    NA
   11-21    8
   12-13    6
```

So what I want to do is create a new column calculating Delta T or change in temperature from one sampling date to the next one, and so on. If there is an NA, I want to avoid it and do the calculation using the last sampled temperature. But I have no idea how to write that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
df$TempDiff <- c(NA_real_, diff(zoo::na.locf(df$`Temp(C)`)))
```

`na.locf` means replacing an `NA` with the most recent non-NA prior to it.

Output looks like this

```
# A tibble: 7 x 3
  Date  `Temp(C)` TempDiff
  <chr>     <dbl>    <dbl>
1 09-22      14       NA  
2 09-29      19.6      5.6
3 10-15      NA        0  
4 10-28      11       -8.6
5 11-06      NA        0  
6 11-21       8       -3  
7 12-13       6       -2
```

To do it by group

```
df <- dplyr::group_by(df, Well)
dplyr::mutate(df, TempDiff = c(NA_real_, diff(zoo::na.locf(`Temp(C)`))))
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 7 x 4
# Groups:   Well [2]
  Date  `Temp(C)`  Well TempDiff
  <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
1 09-22      14       1     NA  
2 09-29      19.6     1      5.6
3 10-15      NA       1      0  
4 10-28      11       2     NA  
5 11-06      NA       2      0  
6 11-21       8       2     -3  
7 12-13       6       2     -2
```

Comment: Is there a way that I can sepearate the difference calculations based on well number. Like say 1-3 was measured from well 1. and 4-7 was measured from well 2. Is there something I could add so the calculation is only done on values from well 1and then values from well 2

Comment: Hi @JackWassik, check my update. Also, if this answer or any other one has solved your question, please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to `zoo::na.locf` we can use `fill` from tidyr package

```
> library(dplyr)
> library(tidyr)
 
> df %>% 
    fill(`Temp(C)`) %>% 
    mutate(Temp2 = c(NA, diff(`Temp(C)`)))
   Date Temp(C) Temp2
1 09-22    14.0    NA
2 09-29    19.6   5.6
3 10-15    19.6   0.0
4 10-28    11.0  -8.6
5 11-06    11.0   0.0
6 11-21     8.0  -3.0
7 12-13     6.0  -2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

a `data.table` oneliner

```
library( data.table )
setDT(mydata)[ !is.na( Temp ), delta := Temp - shift(Temp, type = "lag")]

#   Date Temp delta
# 1: 09-22 14.0    NA
# 2: 09-29 19.6   5.6
# 3: 10-15   NA    NA
# 4: 10-28 11.0  -8.6
# 5: 11-06   NA    NA
# 6: 11-21  8.0  -3.0
# 7: 12-13  6.0  -2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need in percentages:

```
> t %>% filter(!is.na(`Temp(C)` )) %>% mutate(delta_T = paste0(round(100*(`Temp(C)` - lag(`Temp(C)`))/lag(`Temp(C)`)),'%')) %>% right_join(t) %>% arrange(Date)
Joining, by = c("Date", "Temp(C)")
# A tibble: 7 x 3
  Date  `Temp(C)` delta_T
  <chr>     <dbl> <chr>  
1 09-22      14   NA%    
2 09-29      19.6 40%    
3 10-15      NA   NA     
4 10-28      11   -44%   
5 11-06      NA   NA     
6 11-21       8   -27%   
7 12-13       6   -25%
```